# sequential methods execution obj-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, methods

Very beginner obj-c question.

My task is to do simple sequence when view loads:

- pause 2 secons
- method1 execution
- pause 2 seconds
- method2 execution
- pause 2 seconds
- method3 execution

I write this code for iOS5+ so blocks or other features can be used. I tried

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:x];
```

to make the pauses between methods executions, but three pauses added to one  and I have one big pause, so it's wrong piece.
How to do this in right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sleeping an NSThread is never the right way to handle timed method execution.  You want [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html), which you can set to either fire the same method after two seconds (then have that method determine which selector to perform next), or have three timers set to fire two seconds after each other, each calling a different method.

Answer (score 3):

You could use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:, or as CodaFi said, an NSTimer. Either method allows to to pass an object to the method, and that object could be an array or dictionary, if you need to pass multiple arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I'd chain the methods:

- call 1. method and make it call 2.
- 1. method should call 3.
- 1. should proceed to 4.
     ...

Comment: Somewhat brittle though, if he ever needs to use them for something else and they don't depend on each other.

Comment: well he could have a property 'nextMethod' with contains the logic.

Comment: Fair enough but then you have to have some state that keeps track of which one you're on. Then what happens when he initiates this himself and then somehow the user initiates it while these timers are triggering? Then you have a situation in which your counter that counts which method you're on increments too many times and you get out of sync so then you need to have a queue that holds all of the calls to that series of methods until each 3-method chain has been completed etc etc etc. At the end of the day though since we don't know what the methods do it's all speculation so I'll leave it be